# Related List Custom Button for Community using Napili template

Tags: custom-button, community, custom

I am using a Related List custom button To Open a VF page. It is working in classic as well as in Lightning. But not in community. I am using "Napili template" for Community. Is there any workaround for this ?

FYI - All required permissions are given. I also try by changing it to a Javascript button and URL.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having this same issue

Comment: I am having the same trouble. Were you able to figure it out.

Comment: Were you able to this one out ?